# foundation framework - folders messed up

Tags: sass, zurb-foundation

fresh install of the framework.

When I open the app.scss with ruby:
sass --watch app.scss:app.css

I get an error - "fail to import files a b c ..."

That error is expected since all along the foundation scss files there are "important" ref's to files that aren't there!

Starting with the foundation.scss itself.

Any ideas why this happens and how to get it to work?

I'm working locally on windows btw.

The sequence of install I did:
ruby -> sass -> compass -> zurb-foundation

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Having the same problem too. Still looking for answers on this subject.

Answer (score 0):

I am late here but I think this will help others as well.

Download Foundation master from https://github.com/zurb/foundation

get foundation.scss file from scss folder inside foundation-master folder.

Rename it to _foundation.scss and put it inside the sass folder of your project, _foundation.scss file has everything in it so it will fix you r problem I think.